# How to attach an object for collision check in motion planning

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to use MoveIt! for planning motion avoiding collisions between robot links and collision object attached to the end effector of the robot manually and finding usages by simply calling several ROS services instead of using any interface (e.g. MoveGroupInterface) for the simplicity of codes.

It looks there are at least two ways to tell a planner about attached objects to robot links.
My question is which API is better to use, from the perspective of function, difficulty and support.

1. Use of `/apply_planning_scene` service, then `/plan_kinematic_path` service

   Firstly, call `/apply_planning_scene` which takes `moveit_msgs/ApplyPlanningScene`, where we can define attached collision objects by setting them in `ApplyPlanningSceneRequest.scene.robot_state.attached_collision_objects`.
   After receiving its result with a boolean `success` set to `true`, then call `/plan_kinematic_path` for getting the result of motion planning.

   I tried this method, but I doubt a planner actually consider attached collision objects on motion planning, because it sometimes produces trajectory which contains collision in the middle of it.
2. Use of `/plan_kinematic_path` service only

   The service `/plan_kinematic_path` takes `moveit_msgs/GetMotionPlan` service, which also has a field for describing collision objects at `GetMotionPlanRequest.motion_plan_request.start_state.attached_collision_objects`.
   Is it enough to set the field with initial robot joint state and the target one?

   I tried the method too and also got trajectory which contains points in collision.

Or is there any other proper way to use planning service for getting planned motion avoiding collisions between attached objects and robots?

Any suggestion or comment are very welcome!
Thank you very much in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363462/how-to-attach-an-object-for-collision-check-in-motion-planning/) by [furushchev](https://answers.ros.org/users/22201/furushchev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-10-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-10-15**:
You do need to attach collision objects to the robot for it to be considered in collision checking, but the `/plan_kinematic_path` service uses the `attached_collision_objects` provided in the message (including if you don't supply any). Could you provide examples of trajectories that contain collisions?

**Comment by [furushchev](https://answers.ros.org/users/22201/furushchev/) on 2020-11-30**:
@fvd Thank you for the comment and sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, I cannot make the test case public right now, but found how to use planning with attached collision objects correctly (which I "answered").
Anyway, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After several months, we found the cause of this issue.

As for No.2 in my question, we got trajectory which contains points in collision because the collision objects which is set in `GetMotionPlanRequest.motion_plan_request.start_state.attached_collision_objects` accidentally have the same name as robot link names.
Since, we guess, MoveIt! assumes there is only one name space on collision objects including robot links and attached collision objects, they are just ignored and it generated plan including collision.

After renaming the attached collision objects by adding unique prefix, we confirmed that there is no more collision in planned path.

---

Originally posted by [furushchev](https://answers.ros.org/users/22201/furushchev/) with karma: 26 on 2020-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-11-30**:
Thanks for following up! I made a [MoveIt issue](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/2438) to avoid this edge case in the future.

**Comment by [furushchev](https://answers.ros.org/users/22201/furushchev/) on 2020-11-30**:
@fvd Thank you very much!!